# Handling 0 vales when using DATEADD SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck and looking for some help.  So I am trying to use DATEADD and CONVERT in SQL. I have no control over modifying the table or the data type.  Below is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ES.ELC,
ES.UNIT_ID AS UNIT,
ES.MISSION_DESIGN_SERIES AS MDS,
ES.EQUIP_ID AS EQP,
ES.OWNING_WCR AS WCR,
ES.SUD_KEY,
ES.SUD_SORTIE_DATE_UJ5 AS SORTIE_DATE,
ES.SUD_SORTIE_NBR AS SORTIE_NUM,
ES.SUD_SORTIE_MOD AS MOD,
ES.SUD_SCH_UNSCH_IND AS SCH_UNSCH,
ES.SUD_SCH_START_DATE_UJ7 AS SCH_STARTDTE,
ES.SUD_SCH_START_TIME_U4 AS SCH_STARTTM,
ES.SUD_SCH_STOP_DATE_UJ7 AS SCH_STOPDTE,
ES.SUD_SCH_STOP_TIME_U4 AS SCH_STOPTM,
ES.SUD_TYPE_EVENT AS TYPE,
ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_DATE_UJ7 AS STARTDTE,
ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_TIME_U4 AS STARTTM,
ES.SUD_ACTUAL_STOP_DATE_UJ7 AS STOPDTE,
ES.SUD_ACTUAL_STOP_TIME_U4 AS STOPTM,
ES.FLT_LANDING_STATUS AS LS,
SD.DEVIATION_CODE,
SD.CAUSE_CODE,
SD.EVENT_KEY AS JCN,
SD.REMARKS,
SE.EVT_KEY AS LS_JCN,
SE.EVT_CAP_CODE AS CAP_CODE,
SE.EVT_CAP_SYS_CODE AS SYS_CODE,
SE.EVT_ORIG_WUC_DATA AS WUC,
SE.EVT_REPEAT_NBR AS REPEAT,
SE.EVT_RECUR_NBR AS RECUR,
ES.SUD_NUM_LANDINGS AS LANDINGS,
ES.SUD_NUM_FULL_STOPS AS FULL_STOPS,
ES.SUD_NUM_SORTIES AS NUM_SORITES,
ES.SUD_STRESS_FACTOR AS STRESS_FACTOR,
ES.SUD_LAUNCH_BASE_CODE AS LAUNCH_BASE,
ES.SUD_RECOV_BASE_CODE AS RECOV_BASE,
ES.FLT_SORTIE_EFF AS EFF,
ES.FLT_SORTIE_OF_DAY AS SORTIE_OF_DAY,
ES.FLT_MISSION_CODE AS MISSION_CODE,
ES.AUC_CODE,
ES.FLT_PILOT_NAME AS PILOT_NAME,
ES.FLT_DEBRIEFER_NAME AS DEBRIEFER_NAME,

CASE WHEN ES.SUD_SCH_START_DATE_UJ7 <> '0' THEN      
DATEADD(MI, CAST(RIGHT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_TIME_U4,2) AS INT),
DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(LEFT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_TIME_U4,2) AS INT),
CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(DAY,RIGHT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_DATE_UJ7,3)-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_DATE_UJ7,4))))
 ) )
ELSE 'NULL'
END AS STDATE2



FROM
DBO.EQUIP_SUD ES
LEFT JOIN FS.SORTIE_DEVIATIONS SD
ON ES.ELC = SD.ELC
AND ES.SUD_KEY = SD.SUD_KEY

LEFT JOIN DBO.SUD_EVENT SE
ON ES.ELC = SE.ELC
AND ES.UNIT_ID = SE.UNIT_ID
AND ES.SUD_KEY = SE.SUD_KEY


WHERE
ES.ELC = '5362'
AND
ES.UNIT_ID LIKE 'A'
AND
ES.SUD_SORTIE_DATE_UJ5 >= '22104'
AND
ES.SUD_SORTIE_DATE_UJ5 <= '22104'

ORDER BY ES.SUD_SORTIE_DATE_UJ5 ASC, ES.SUD_SORTIE_NBR ASC
```

I get the following error when I run it:
Line 1: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know my problem is the following code:

```
CASE WHEN ES.SUD_SCH_START_DATE_UJ7 IS NOT NULL THEN      
DATEADD(MI, CAST(RIGHT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_TIME_U4,2) AS INT),
DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(LEFT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_TIME_U4,2) AS INT),
CONVERT(DATETIME, 
DATEADD(DAY,RIGHT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_DATE_UJ7,3)-1,
 CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(ES.SUD_ACTUAL_START_DATE_UJ7,4))))
 ) )
ELSE 'NULL'
END AS STDATE2
```

I can't figure out how to convert this due to the 0 values.
The columns in question are decimal data types.
When these columns don't have julian dates and time in them, they are filled with a 0.

Comment: What kind of date is 22104? 104th day of 2022?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes it is.

Comment: This would be much more clear if you would provide us with some sample data and expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the DATEADD functions to return when the fields contain zero?
Add another CASE to handle the zeros to return your expected result.

Declare some test data with some known values and zeros, isolate and test that code outside the select statement.

Comment: I want it to ignore the zeros convert the actual values.

Comment: @WilliamHoward Then the question still stands, what are you expecting the DATEADD function to return when the fields contain zero

Comment: If you want to ignore the zero values, maybe you need to add a condition to your WHERE clause to exclude those records that contain zeros.